# how to code random rotational transformation of input images in Tensorflow?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning

Are there any APIs or code for doing on-the-fly random rotational augmentation in Tensorflow while feeding the image data?
Are there any codes to wrap up regular random rotational transformation function to Tensorflow function?

Comment: This could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40560101/how-to-do-image-rotation-in-tensorflow

Answer (score 0):

Keras has some functions for data augmentation and is built on top of tensorflow. It is very easy to use and install. You can check documentation [here](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/)